# How do I create an ordered integer key from a set of integer values with left-to-right priority?

Tags: c++, sorting, integer

This is one of those questions where it's probably answered somewhere, and probably quite simple, I just can't find the right search terms.

I have a set of objects that I need to insert into an ordered container (e.g. `std::map`), insertion performance is a high-priority. Up until now I've been using a fairly complex `<` operator, but profiling shows that this is taking a bunch of time.

What I'd like to do is pre-calculate an integer value for each object for sorting, so that the `<` operator simply becomes an integer comparison.

Essentially I have a set of 12 unsigned integer values in priority order, each has its own possible range of values (the largest being 0-100000, the smallest being 0-1).

It's difficult to explain, but imagine two objects, each with an array of 12 values. If value [0] is greater on one object then its sort key must be higher, if value[0] is equal, but value[1] is greater than the other object, then its sort key must be higher. I hope that makes sense...

It feels like there should be an obvious way to generate a key from these values but I'm having trouble with it.

Comment: "ordered container (e.g. `std::unordered_map`)"?

Comment: Well, there is, but the straight-forward approach might become too wide to be practical.

Comment: Whats the key, whats the actual container? You don't use `<` with a `std::unordered_map`, it wants a hash function and equality (`==`). And `std::unordered_map` is unordered, use say `std::map` if you want ordered transversal.

Comment: Twelve 17-bit numbers can be packed into four 64-bit ones.

Comment: Sorry I meant `std::map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well performance i.e. profiling questions are always a bit problematic, but this is the first solution I came up, which should be close to the C++ portable optimum, at least I hope. The 3 simple `cmp` x64 instruction let me believe that.

And you can remove the `constexpr` before `inline bool compare1`, its only supported by the very latest C++20 implementations:

https://godbolt.org/z/LdEk4M

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

constexpr unsigned value_count = 12;
using value_t = uint_fast32_t;

struct object{
    std::array<value_t , value_count> values{};
};

constexpr inline bool compare1(const object& objecta, const object& objectb) {
    bool result{false};
    auto [mismatcha, mismatchb] = std::mismatch(objecta.values.begin(), objecta.values.end(), objectb.values.begin());

    if (mismatcha != objecta.values.end()) {
        result = *mismatcha < *mismatchb;
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<value_t> dist(0, 100000);
    constexpr size_t object_count{50000};
    std::cout << "Generate " << object_count << " random objects" << std::endl;
    std::vector<object> unsorted_objects;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(unsorted_objects), object_count, [&] () {
        object val{};
        std::generate(val.values.begin(), val.values.end(), [&]() {
            return dist(rd); });
        return val;
    });
    std::set<object, decltype(&compare1)> objects(&compare1);
    std::cout << "Generating sorted i.e. ordered container" << std::endl;
    std::move(unsorted_objects.begin(), unsorted_objects.end(), std::inserter(objects,objects.end()));
}
```

I think precomputing a "score" is not what you described in your question, since it seems to me, you have a 12xunsigned number you want to compare. So your score would have to be the same thing. At best your could save the first bit or value position which is not 1 i.e. not the maximal possible value. But that conditional jump could already be more costly than compare the 12 integers pipelined.